# How to update multiple records from search/view/SOQL using Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have an update action, where I need to update a varying number of objects (these can be created as a view, report, csv file, excel file, simple paste into window).

I want that my users will get a visual form, where they can select the report/view/paste values, enter the desired new data to update, and click submit.

- If I use a dynamic Choice list, than this is hardcoded, and can't be changed by users.
- I don't mind the report/view will only show ID's (If that can make any difference)
  -

[image: Something like this]

This way, all 'returned' id's, will get the new fields values.

---

Another option I had in mind, is to be able to paste in the selected ID's of the objects to update (even with a limit of rows - say 50)

So, the user will have to do some tweaks, and get the list of ID's to update

[image]

That requires scrapping/looping over the 'long text area' - not sure if this is at all possible.

- Pasting the SOQL seems the worst of options, since I can't have my users learn SOQL ;-)

Any thoughts on the direction to take here?

The task should be accessible by 15% of my users, so it's widely spread. And I need it to be easy to use/handle.

Comment: If you want to use list views as a source, why not using standard inline editing in the list view as a mechanism to edit?

Comment: this can cause 100's of records, inline edit is out of the question

Comment: What is the restriction then? You could display up to 200 records, and update all of them in one shot by selecting multiple records using the checkboxes, double clicking the field you want to edit and selecting 'all selected records'. You were suggesting manually copy pasting 50 record IDs... Or am I missing something?

Comment: 50 was an example, but I didnt' know the update with the select checkbox.

Comment: I just wanted to state you could do 200 at once using complete standard functionality. Up to you to decide if working around this limit is worth custom development.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you are trying to build a UI/VF where user can select ListView/Report etc and then you want to mass update records related to them.

Well if this is the case then the answer is below.

## 1 if you are showing listview -> you can pull max 10000 records related to that list view in apex using standardsetController and then can perform your operation.

## 2 limit here is 2000, if your records in a report are more then 2000 then you can get the conditions of report and can build a query for the same to fetch the records)

let me know if you need ore information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting from a list view.  This provides a better experience for selecting records instead of a dynamic choice.  Also multiselect w dynamic choice is not straightforward and has some limitations.

From a list view, you can pass the selected IDs to the flow using [this technique described by Andrew Fawcett](https://www.google.com/amp/s/andyinthecloud.com/2014/06/04/more-power-to-your-flows-in-summer14/amp/) that uses a simple visualforce page to launch the flow.

If you want to try using a dynamic choice, you can check [this post about using dynamic choice w multiselect](http://goravseth.com/using-a-dynamic-choice-to-select-multiple-records-in-visual-workflow)